# Hadoop start dfs permission denied for "hadoop" user

Tags: hadoop, homebrew

I have setup hadoop on mac local mac. When i start-dfs using the `start-dfs.sh` command using a separate `hadoop` user i get the following error in the terminal.

`0.0.0.0: mkdir: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs: Permission denied`

Does anyone know how i can change the log directory for hadoop? I installed hadoop using homebrew.

```
bash-3.2$ start-dfs.sh  
14/03/31 09:04:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  
Starting namenodes on [localhost]  
localhost: mkdir: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs: Permission denied  
localhost: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs: No such file or directory  
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mymac.local.out
localhost: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 151: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mymac.local.out: No such file or directory  
localhost: head: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mymac.local.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 166: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mymac.local.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 167: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mymac.local.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs: Permission denied
localhost: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/logs: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You mentioned that you are using a separate `hadoop` user. Have you tried to change the ownership of the hadoop folder to user `hadoop`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error indicates a permissions problem. The hadoop user needs the proper privileges to the hadoop folder. Try running the following in Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R hadoop /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/
```